# Azure REST API: How to get SQL Server users/admin

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

In the Azure Portal, when navigating to a SQL Server, I can see/edit it's users and AD Admin.

Is there a way to get/list all users & admin(s) of SQL Server via API?
Looking thru the [Azure API Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163571.aspx) I couldn't find any such API.

Edit:
By SQL Users I mean users set via:
[image]
By AD Admin I mean the user set via:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users: [via powershell](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-manage-access-powershell/) or [via REST](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-manage-access-rest/) 
- see "List role assignments at a specific scope"

AD Administrator: [via powershell](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-aad-authentication/)- see "Provision an Azure AD administrator for Azure SQL Server by using PowerShell". There  seems to be a reference that would indicate an intent to expose this via the REST API, but it seems to be missing from the documentation. Let me see what we can do about that.

---

**Edit**: The powershell command that would list all Role assignments for a specific SQL server would be:

`Get-AzureRmRoleAssignment -ResourceGroupName <your resource group name> -ResourceType Microsoft.Sql/servers -ResourceName <your server name> -IncludeClassicAdministrators`

A similar approach is possible with the REST commands.

Important to note: This only enumerates the Azure permission set, and no RBAC on the SQL Server level is enumerated here.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for!  can you elaborate on the use of <code>atScope()</> ?what is its parameter?

Comment: On which approach are you asking for more guidance?

Comment: I'd like to receive the users who's role includes access to specific resource. e.g. SQL Server, as in my original question

Comment: If you're asking for help with the REST commands specifically, please specify.

Comment: Thanks, I've managed to use this API for all that I needed, except for getting the admin - any idea when/if this will be exposed via the API?