# what role is needed to allow creating new databases with master database in Azure SQL data base

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a requirement, where I need to create a new database in a azure SQL database by opening a master connection. So for that I need to check if that user have the permission t create new database or not. For tradition SQL, I am providing 'dbcreator' roll to user and

```
string query = "SELECT IS_SRVROLEMEMBER('dbcreator') IS_DBCREATOR";
```

using above query to check the if the user have permission to create new database.

Now same thing I have to implement over azure SQL database. So what roll I have to assign to user/server so I will allow to create new databases. And what query I need to use to check if user have creator permission.

Comment: Is this Azure SQL Database or Azure Database MySQL; those are 2 *completely* different products. If the former, you cannot do this with a server role; you have to do it from the Azure Portal.

Comment: @ThomA, I am using Azure SQL Database, So what roll I need to assign it, So It will allow to create new data bases with c# code.

Comment: None, you need to use the Azure Portal or APIs. You cannot issue a `CREATE DATABASE` statement in Azure SQL Database.

Comment: *Also it's a **role**, not a roll (as in to roll over, or a bread roll).*

Comment: I am able to execute CREATE DATABASE query successfully, but only problem is how to validate if user have permission to execute this query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the [CREATE DATABASE documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current&preserve-view=true&tabs=sqlpool#permissions-1):

> To create a database, the user login must be one of the following
> principals:
>
> - The server-level principal login
> - The Azure AD administrator for the local Azure SQL Server
> - A login that is a member of the dbmanager database role

For the `dbmanager` role membership, the user needs a server level login, a master database user, and membership of the `dbmanager` database role.

Example to grant an existing login permissions to create databases in `master` database context:

```
CREATE USER YourDbCreatorUser;
ALTER ROLE dbmanager ADD MEMBER YourDbCreatorUser;
```

To check the current user for `dbmanager` database role membership (in the `master` database context):

```
SELECT IS_MEMBER('dbmanager') IS_DBMANAGER;
```

To check if the current user has `CREATE DATABASE` permissions via `dbmanager` role membership or other means (e.g. administrator), use one of the methods below:

```
SELECT HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME(NULL, NULL, 'CREATE ANY DATABASE') AS HasCreateDatabasePermissions; 

SELECT COALESCE((SELECT 1
    FROM fn_my_permissions ( NULL, 'SERVER' )
    WHERE permission_name = 'CREATE ANY DATABASE'), 0) AS HasCreateDatabasePermissions;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am able to create new data base but, while executing this "SELECT IS_MEMBER('dbmanager') IS_DBMANAGER;"  its returning 0. Ideally if it is allowing to create new data base then this should return 1.

Comment: @AbhishekMaurya, I updated my answer with `HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME` too.

Comment: HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME  query also returning 0.

Comment: @AbhishekMaurya, I updated my answer with another method that should work for other permission paths.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of **dbmanager** and **loginmanager** roles to grant **permission** to the user to create a new database. Connect to the master database with server admin and run the **below command** to add a role to the user:

```
ALTER ROLE dbmanager ADD MEMBER <user>;
ALTER ROLE loginmanager ADD MEMBER <user>;
```

[image]

Connect to the master database with the user and `create database <dbName>` to create the table. It will run successfully as shown below:

[image]

The database will be created successfully as shown below:

[image]

For more information you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39259559/how-to-check-if-user-has-create-database-access-in-sql-azure#:%7E:text=2%20Answers&text=You%20can%20edit%20db_owner%20to,database%20as%20the%20dbo%20user.).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am able to create new data base but, while executing this "SELECT IS_MEMBER('dbmanager') IS_DBMANAGER;" its returning 0. Ideally if it is allowing to create new data base then this should return 1. Or suggest any other way so I can check if user have 'dbmanager' permission.

Comment: Did you run that command in master database?

Comment: Yes I tried it on master